# Assassin creed 2 figurine help

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Where are all the statues or figurines on assassins creed 2? I have looked through all the maps but haven't found them.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you mean the villa statues. The location are shown in this image below.

on the [same page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-2/Villa_Statues_Map) there is a link to a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ia6JAPnKPs) in case you still can not find them with the help of this image.

[image]